# How to parse a string to DateTime?

Tags: dart

How can I make this work ?

```
DateTime test = DateTime.parse("31.01.2020 00:00:00");
```

It gives this error:

> "Invalid date format 31.01.2020 00:00:00"

Comment: Because the format are not valid according to: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html ?

Comment: @julemand101 ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `intl` package.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime test = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss').parse("31.01.2020 00:00:00");
```